# Couchbase Server on Mac: cbdocloader not installed

Tags: macos, couchbase, bulkloader, bulk-load

I have installed Couchbase Server 3.0 on Mac OSX 1.9.5 using the package from couchbase, installed using all defaults, and I am not able to locate cbdocloader in the expected folder

```
 /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/tools
```

The only tools available are:

```
 cbanalyze-core 
 vbucketkeygen  
 vbuckettool
```

I do not see any information about the deprecation of this tool or an alternative approach to load data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong folder, it's in `bin` and not `tools`:

```
[user:~] $ /Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbdocloader -h
Usage: cbdocloader [options] <directory>|zipfile

Example: cbdocloader -u Administrator -p password -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -b mybucket -s 100 gamesim-sample.zip

Options:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -u Administrator   Username
  -p password        Password
  -b mybucket        Bucket
  -n 127.0.0.1:8091  Node address
  -s 100             RAM quota in MB
```

Comment: YOU are a star - and I cannot read. Thanks a lot. In the meantime I wanted to play with the Python client to code this myself, and I cannot figure how to struggle with the libcouchbase compilation an python dependencies install (pip did not work). teething problems...

Comment: Have you install libcouchbase? (assuming OSX: `brew install libcouchbase`) If you open a new question or put the error here, I will have a look.